# Is there a way to find the time difference between these two formats? using datetime

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

I get the departure variable by asking for it as input into a string. Using this code as shortened version to show where it starts.

```
departure = "2022-11-12 14:30"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(departure, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
current_time = datetime.utcnow()
print(datetime_object-timedelta(current_time))
```

I am trying to subtract this and basically receive any sort of outcome in days + mins +seconds or in just one variable like minutes. i.e.

```
>>> 
10000 mins
```

What I am currently getting is this

```
>>>
print(datetime_object-timedelta(current_time))
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Just `datetime_object-current_time`? The result will be timedelta...

Comment: wow man this worked, i appreciate you more than you know